# Change the width of black block

Tags: html, css

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.block1 {
  width: 10%;
  height: inherit;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  animation: boxincrease 2s cubic-bezier(0.74, 0.86, 0.4, 0.92) forwards;
}

@keyframes boxincrease {
  0% {
    width: 10%;
    left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0%;
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nameintro">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="block1"></div>
    <h1>XYZ<span>.</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="role">
    <div class="block2"></div>
    <p>AMATEUR ARTIST</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to change the width of the black block as it is covering the whole width of the page i want it to cover only the part where xyz written.
I want to make something like this without using scss.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7d2XsPSjjjI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the "box" width to fit content so that it doesn't exceed the text and set the position relative to it.

```css
.box {
  width: fit-content;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.block1 {
  height: inherit;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  animation: boxincrease 2s cubic-bezier(0.74, 0.86, 0.4, 0.92) forwards;
}

@keyframes boxincrease {
  0% {
    width: 10%;
    left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0%;
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nameintro">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="block1"></div>
    <h1>XYZ<span>.</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="role">
    <div class="block2"></div>
    <p>AMATEUR ARTIST</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can I specify the width ? like width : 300px or something

Comment: why do i have to set tthe position to relative?

Comment: By setting the parent to position relative, you are making sure that the child doesn't exceed the parent container.

Answer (score 2):

Adjust the values in your keyframe,

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.block1 {
  width: 10%;
  height: inherit;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  animation: boxincrease 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.74, 0.86, 0.4, 0.92) forwards;
}

@keyframes boxincrease {
  0% {
    width: 10%;
    left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 15%;
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0%;
    left: 15%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nameintro">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="block1"></div>
    <h1>XYZ<span>.</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="role">
    <div class="block2"></div>
    <p>AMATEUR ARTIST</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a grid and put the blocks in the same grid column example;

```css
.nameintro {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(30px, auto);
}

.box {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: 300px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(30px, auto);
}

.one {
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.two {
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

.role {
  grid-column: 2 / 2
}

.block1 {
  background-color: black;
  animation: boxincrease 2s cubic-bezier(0.74, 0.86, 0.4, 0.92) forwards;
}

@keyframes boxincrease {
  0% {
    width: 10%;
    left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0%;
    left: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nameintro">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="one block1"></div>
    <h1 class="two">XYZ<span>.</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="role">
    <div class="block2"></div>
    <p>AMATEUR ARTIST</p>
  </div>
</div>
```